# Pushing a floating <div> down instead of beside another float above it using CSS

Tags: css, html, css-float

I have docbook generated HTML that contains small, fixed size images. All these images have the CSS property `float: right` These usually work as expected, but if two appear close together, they may not have enough room and will push against each other and alter the page layout, like this:

[image: Float right divs pushing against each other]

What I want to happen is for the div to be pushed down. If it's vertical position changes, that's ok, so long as the horizontal position is always right aligned, like this:

[image: Float right divs correctly lined up]

I want to be able to do this with CSS, but a Javascript solution would work too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should just be able to add `clear: both;` to the CSS for the images - this will cause them to move down to avoid hitting another `float`ed element.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a margin to the image. Also make sure there is a break `<br />` between lines.

```
margin:10px;
```

Comment: I can't manually add line breaks to the HTML since it's automatically generated from xml and used for both PDF and HTML. Increasing the top/bottom margins would actually make the problem worse.